# If one region is above the $x$-axis, and the other below it, should "the ratio of their areas" use absolute value?

Tags: integration, ratio

Good morning mathematicians,

I apologize for asking such a basic question. When you are to find the ratio of "Area 1" and "Area 2", such that "Area 1" is the area of a region *above* the x-axis and "Area 2" is the area of a region *below* the x-axis, are you looking for an absolute value of the ratio, or do you leave the value negative?

Comment: It depends on context. After all, treating below-the-$x$-axis regions as having *negative* area is a key element in how integration *works*, so "maybe" the ratio here should be considered negative if this is an integration exercise. On the other hand, if you simply *happen* to be using integration as a means of computing the areas of a couple of geometric figures, one of which just *happens* to be below the $x$-axis, then it's likely that "area" should be taken in absolute value. Authors sometimes avoid confusion by writing, say, "the ratio of the *signed* areas".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, areas are always non-negative numbers, so a ratio of areas should also be non-negative (i.e. if the result is negative, the absolute value is taken).